How to Prove Division of One Bezier Curve into Two using de Casteljau Algorithm
$\newcommand{\brstbasis}[2]{b^{#1}_{#2}}$
$\newcommand{\posintset}{\mathbb{Z}^{+}}$
$\newcommand{\intset}{\mathbb{Z}}$
$\newcommand{\realset}{\mathbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\domain}[1]{\operatorname{dom}\left(#1\right)}$
To provide background for this proof, first we define De Casteljau coefficients. Let $n \in \posintset$ and $p$ be a sequence of size $n + 1$ and $\tau \in \left(0, 1\right)$. We say $c$ is a deCateljau function of $p$ with respect to $\tau$ if and only if $c$ is a function such that $\domain{c} = \intset \times \intset$ and for any $i, j \in \intset$,
\begin{equation}
c\left(i, j\right) = 
\begin{cases}
p_{i},\ 0 \leq i \leq n \wedge j = 0\\
0,\ i < 0 \vee i > n \vee \left(0 \leq i \leq n \wedge \left(j < 0 \vee j > i\right)\right)\\
\left(1 - \tau\right) c\left(i - 1, j - 1\right) + \tau c\left(i, j - 1\right),\  \textrm{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
De Casteljau Algorithm has two parts, one is for evaluation of a Bezier curve at an arbitrary point $t \in \left[0, 1\right]$, while the other one is to divide a Bezier curve into two using the same set of Bernstein bases.
The first part can be summarized as follows. Let $n \in \posintset$, $p$ be a sequence of $n + 1$ points, $r$ be a Bezier curve such that for any $t \in \left[0, 1\right]$,
\begin{equation*}
r\left(t\right) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} p_{k} \brstbasis{n}{k}\left(t\right).
\end{equation*}
Also, let $\tau \in \left(0, 1\right)$ and $c$ be the de Casteljau coefficients of $p$ with respect to $\tau$. Then for any $i, j \in \intset$, if $0 \leq j \leq n$ and $j \leq i \leq n$, then
\begin{equation*}
c\left(i, j\right) = \sum_{k=0}^{j}p_{i - j + k} \brstbasis{j}{k}\left(\tau\right).
\end{equation*}
In particular,
\begin{equation*}
c\left(n, n\right) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} p_{k} \brstbasis{n}{k}\left(\tau\right) = r\left(\tau\right).
\end{equation*}
I have proved the first part using mathematical induction, and I am stuck on proving the second part. The second part can be summarized as follows. Let $n \in \posintset$, $p$ be a sequence of $n + 1$ points, $r$ be a Bezier curve such that for any $t \in \left[0, 1\right]$,
\begin{equation*}
r\left(t\right) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} p_{k} \brstbasis{n}{k}\left(t\right).
\end{equation*}
Also, let $\tau \in \left(0, 1\right)$ and $c$ be the de Casteljau coefficients of $p$ with respect to $\tau$. Further, let $\Gamma$ and $\Psi$ be sets of points of the two partitions of $r$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\Gamma = \left\{x \in \realset \vert x = r\left(t\right) \textrm{ for some } t \in \left[0, \tau\right]\right\}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\Psi = \left\{x \in \realset \vert x = r\left(t\right) \textrm{ for some } t \in \left[\tau, 1\right]\right\},
\end{equation*}
$\alpha$ and $\beta$ be Bezier curves such that for any $t \in \left[0,1\right]$,
\begin{equation*}
\alpha\left(t\right) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} c\left(i, i\right) \brstbasis{n}{i}\left(t\right)
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\beta\left(t\right) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} c\left(n, n - i\right) \brstbasis{n}{i}\left(t\right),
\end{equation*}
and $S$ and $T$ are points of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that
\begin{equation*}
S = \left\{x \in \realset \vert x = \alpha\left(t\right) \textrm{ for some } t \in \left[0, 1\right]\right\}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
T = \left\{x \in \realset \vert x = \beta\left(t\right) \textrm{ for some } t \in \left[0, 1\right]\right\}.
\end{equation*}
Then $\Gamma = S$ and $\Psi = T$.
I am trying to use mathematical induction to prove the second part. Let $P$ be the predicate such that for any $n \in \posintset$, $P\left(n\right)$ if and only if the statement holds for $n$.
First we examine $P\left(0\right)$. In this case, for any $t \in \left[0, 1\right]$, $r\left(t\right) = p_{0}$. Then $\Gamma = \left\{p_{0}\right\}$ and $\Phi = \left\{p_{0}\right\}$. Further, by \cref{def: de casteljau coefficients}, $c\left(0, 0\right) = p_{0}$.
Then for any $t \in \left[0,1\right]$, $\alpha_{t} = p_{0}$ and $\beta_{t} = p_{0}$. Consequently, $S = \left\{p_{0}\right\}$ and $T = \left\{p_{0}\right\}$. Finally we have $\Gamma = S$ and $\Phi = T$.
Next, let $n \in \posintset$ and assume that $P\left(n\right)$. It is our desire to prove $P\left(n + 1\right)$. Let $\tau \in \left(0, 1\right)$, $p$ be a sequence of $n + 2$ points, $c$ be the de Casteljau coefficients of $p$. Further, let $r$ be a Bezier curve such that
\begin{equation*}
r\left(t\right) = \sum_{k=0}^{n + 1} p_{k} \brstbasis{n + 1}{k}\left(t\right),
\end{equation*}
$\Gamma$ and $\Psi$ be partitions of $r$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\Gamma = \left\{x \in \realset \vert x = r\left(t\right) \textrm{ for some } t \in \left[0, \tau\right]\right\},
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\Psi = \left\{x \in \realset \vert x = r\left(t\right) \textrm{ for some } t \in \left[\tau, 1\right]\right\}.
\end{equation*}
Further, let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be Bezier curves such that for any $t \in \left[0,1\right]$,
\begin{equation*}
\alpha\left(t\right) = \sum_{i=0}^{n + 1} c\left(i, i\right) \brstbasis{n + 1}{i}\left(t\right)
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\beta\left(t\right) = \sum_{i=0}^{n + 1} c\left(n + 1, n + 1 - i\right) \brstbasis{n + 1}{i}\left(t\right).
\end{equation*}
Also, let $S$ and $T$ be sets such that
\begin{equation*}
S = \left\{x \in \realset \vert x = \alpha\left(t\right) \textrm{ for some } t \in \left[0, 1\right]\right\}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
T = \left\{x \in \realset \vert x = \beta\left(t\right) \textrm{ for some } t \in \left[0, 1\right]\right\}.
\end{equation*}
It is our desire to prove that $S = \Gamma$ and $T = \Psi$.
By the theorem from the first part, for any $i \in \left[0, n + 1\right] \cap \posintset$,
\begin{equation*}
c\left(i, i\right) = \sum_{k=0}^{i} p_{k} \brstbasis{i}{k}\left(\tau\right)
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
c\left(n + 1, n + 1 - i\right) = \sum_{k=0}^{n + 1 - i} p_{i + k} \brstbasis{n + 1 - i}{k}\left(\tau\right).
\end{equation*}
Then
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\alpha\left(t\right) &= \sum_{i=0}^{n + 1} c\left(i, i\right) \brstbasis{n + 1}{i}\left(t\right) = \sum_{i=0}^{n + 1} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{i} p_{k} \brstbasis{i}{k}\left(\tau\right)\right) \brstbasis{n + 1}{i}\left(t\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\beta\left(t\right) = \sum_{i=0}^{n + 1} c\left(n + 1, n + 1 - i\right) \brstbasis{n + 1}{i}\left(t\right) = \sum_{i=0}^{n + 1} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n + 1 - i} p_{i + k} \brstbasis{n + 1 - i}{k}\left(\tau\right)\right) \brstbasis{n + 1}{i}\left(t\right)
\end{equation*}
I am not sure if I am on the right track. Ideally, I should somehow find a way to utilize $P\left(n\right)$. Can anyone help me sort out the path for proof?

See here.

Interesting. The idea of “proving” de Casteljau subdivision never ever occurred to me. People have been using it for more than 60 years, so I guess I always assumed it to be correct. The “proof” just seems like pointless manipulation of symbols, to me.

@bubba Just some personal interest.

The easiest proof is probably via blossoming. Given a polynomial $f$ of degree $m$, there is a unique symmetric mult-affine function $F$ of $m$ variables such that $F(x, \ldots, x) = f(x)$ for all $x$. We call $F$ the blossom or polar form of $f$.
In some sense, the blossom is just a very clever way to label the points that show up in the de Casteljau algorithm. Let’s take the cubic case, to be specific. There is a theorem that says that the Bézier control points of the curve $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$ are just $F(a,a,a)$, $F(a,a,b)$, $F(a,b,b)$, $F(b,b,b)$.
If you use the de Casteljau algorithm to divide this curve segment at $c \in [a,b]$, then you will find (by virtue of the multi-affine property of $F$) that it generates the points $F(a,a,a)$, $F(a,a,c)$, $F(a,c,c)$, $F(c,c,c)$ and $F(c,c,c)$, $F(c,c,b)$, $F(c,b,b)$, $F(b,b,b)$. These are precisely the Bézier control points of the curve segments on the intervals $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$.
For more details, lookup “blossoming of Bézier curves”.
